# Read from File to Listview

Tags: java, listview, bufferedreader

I tried to fetch data from a .txt using buffered Reader etc.
But I just don't get the data into my listview.
Writing works, but not reading.

It doesn't show any errors.
Would appreciate it, if somebody could help finding, what is wrong.

```
    //String family = familyinput.getText().toString();
   // ArrayAdapter<String> famadapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, addFamily);


    public static void writeTextToFile( final String filename, final String data){
        File file = new File(filename);
        try {
                FileOutputStream stream = new FileOutputStream(file,true);
                stream.write(data.getBytes());
                stream.close();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button familybutton;
        EditText familyinput;
        ArrayList<String> addFamily = new ArrayList<>();
        ListView show;
        familybutton = findViewById(R.id.button);
        familyinput = findViewById(R.id.inputsiteFamilie);
        show = findViewById(R.id.listView);
        //Intent intent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);

        
            try{
                String filePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/family.txt";
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(filePath),"CP1252"), 100);

                String line ;
                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null){
                    ArrayAdapter<String> famadapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,addFamily);
                    show.setAdapter(famadapter);
                    addFamily.add(line);
                }
                br.close();
            }
            catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
;
                    });
                }

            };

        });
    }
}
```

Comment: I’m not too familiar with Adapters, but it may be because you’re redefining your `ArrayAdapter` with each iteration of the while loop. I’d suggest waiting until the loop has finished reading the file and then initialize your adapter and add it to show.

Comment: I tried putting the Adapter and show. SetAdapter out of the loop, right before the br.close, but it still doesn't fill the listview with content. Even if I insert a method into the code and a load button, which is supposed to load it, after clicking, it doesn't fill the listview

Comment: Have you tried logging or printing `addFamily` to the console to verify that it's being populated? What does your view template look like?